# phpMyAdmin Service Unavailable

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have just installed fresh fedora 21, httpd, mysql and phpMyAdmin. I get an error if I visit localhost/phpMyAdmin

```
Service Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

Mysql seems to work fine, I can connect to it.

Comment: Not really SO material, but did you go into phpMyAdmin's config file?

Comment: [Tue Apr 07 22:09:22.209566 2015] [proxy:error] [pid 2807] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Tue Apr 07 22:09:22.209597 2015] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2807] [client 127.0.0.1:60928] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In the file **/etc/php.ini** look for  `open_basedir` parameter and assign the path of the app for example **/var/www/html/phpmyadmin**. If you have multiple dirs concatenate them with :

```
open_basedir=/usr/share/webapps/:/etc/webapps/:/tmp/:/srv/http/arch/cacti/:/var/www/html/phpmyadmin
```

Don`t forget to restart the httpd server.

Comment: You can use a backtick (`) or indentation to format text as code. This can be useful to highlight paths or bits of configuration